# Is this algorithm using DP?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

So I have been learning Dynamic Programming (DP) recently and when I came upon the following problem, I decided to use DP but since I'm a beginner in algorithms, I am not sure if this is a valid example of DP or not.

**Problem:**

> *Given an array nums. We define a running sum of an array as runningSum[i] = sum(nums[0]…nums[i]). Return the running sum of nums.*

```
Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
Output: [1,3,6,10]
Explanation: Running sum is obtained as follows: [1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4].
```

This is my "DP" solution:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] runningSum(int[] nums) {
        int[] arr = new int[nums.length];
        
        int sum = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            arr[i] = nums[i] + sum;
            sum += nums[i];
        }
        
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: **NO**. Not, solved using DP.

Comment: Instead of `sum`, you could just use `nums[i-1]`, which would make it a bit more DP like. But I think to truly qualify as DP you'd have to use at least two previous values from `arr` to compute `arr[i]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Computer_programming):

> There are two key attributes that a problem must have in order for dynamic programming to be applicable: optimal substructure and overlapping sub-problems. If a problem can be solved by combining optimal solutions to non-overlapping sub-problems, the strategy is called ["divide and conquer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) instead. This is why merge sort and quick sort are not classified as dynamic programming problems.

In your case, you are implementing following strategy:

```
  sum_all(array) = array[0] + sum_all(array[1..])
```

At each step there is only one subproblem, and that means there is no overlap of the subproblems.  Indeed, this is a degenerate form of divide and conquer.

Answer (score 4):

I think the main thing why I'm hesitant to call your algorithm DP is absence of optimization. Certainly, your task can be divided to smaller subtasks and result for size n assembled from result for size n-1. But DP is optimization strategy. I cannot see anything to be optimized in your task.

Comment: I would not subscribe to this. E.g., the Fibonacci sequence is also a classical DP example, and is not optimization either.

Comment: DP algorithm for Fibonacci sequence stores result of calls at lower level into array, which is optimization because it would be computed repeatedly otherwise. I meant the absence of "overlapping sub-problems" attribute as Stephen C more precisely expressed.

Comment: Well, what OP does could also be considered "optimization", since they could also compute the entire sum again using a nested loop. I think the key difference is that here we do not have _overlapping_ subproblems, thus it's more divide & conquer than DP.

Answer (score 3):

```
Example 1:
Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
Output: [1,3,6,10]
Explanation: Running sum is obtained as follows: [1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4].
```

**Just use this:**

Create a prefix array and every element of this array is the sum of previous element and element of original array

```
int[] P = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  if (i == 0) P[i] = nums[i];
  else P[i] = P[i-1] + nums[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also this is good to use

```
vector<int> P; // running sum list
vector<int> nums = {1,2,3,4}; // given input
int sum = 0; // sum at any running position
for(auto x : nums) 
{
   P.push_back(sum+x);
   sum += x;
}
```